# SAPUI5 - Batch Operations - how to do it right?

Tags: entity, batch-processing, crud, sapui5

I got multiple EntititySets which I want to update in my SAP Backend, therefore I fetch my data (payload) as JSON and put it in a request (its successfully in the node "data"):

Code:

```
var oTreeJSON = oTreeTable.getModel().getProperty("/root");
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
var batchChanges = [];  

for (var i = 0; i < oTreeAll.length; i++) {
    batchChanges.push(oModel.createBatchOperation("/sap/opu/odata/sap/MY_SERVICE/?$batch", "POST", oTreeAll[i]));
}

oModel.submitBatch();
```

My Request looks like this:

[image]

Where should it arrive in SAP (which method)? What am I doing wrong, there is no error anywhere, but no call arrived in my backend... Glad about every hint! Thanks.

**Working example with reduced complexity:**

```
var oEntry = {};
oEntry.MyId = "00000001";
oEntry.Value = "300";

batchChanges.push(oModel.createBatchOperation("MyEntitySet", "POST", oEntry, null));
oModel.addBatchChangeOperations(batchChanges); 
oModel.setUseBatch(true);
oModel.submitBatch();
```

For the record, method calls:

- 1) /IWBEP/IF_MGW_CORE_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_BEGIN: SAP Proposal EXIT.
- 2) /iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~create_entity. (n-times) // do your
  stuff with the entity
- 3) /iwbep/if_mgw_core_srv_runtime~changeset_end: SAP Proposal COMMIT
  WORK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
oModel.addBatchChangeOperations(batchChanges);
oModel.setUseBatch(true);
```

In case you need set a breakpoint in backend for batch operations, just set a break point in method `CHANGESET_BEGIN` or `CHANGESET_END`.

Comment: its not arriving in the backend ... do I have to set any header-data manually? (did not have to set any headers before, all in the same domain, thus I thought its the same this time)... which is the correct method? got breakpoints in /IWBEP/IF_MGW_CORE_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_BEGIN and in /IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_BEGIN, both dont get activated..

Comment: Hi, you need add the batch operations. oModel.addBatchChangeOperations(batchChanges);
oModel.setUseBatch(true);

Comment: I got it running for a version with reduced complexity, now I got to adapt it.. at least the call is being transfered to the backend. I will update my answer, I think your two hints are necessary, so I'll accept it as answer :-)

Comment: `addBatchChangeOperations` is method in `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`, how to do it in `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` ?

Answer (score 1):

Post my POST code for `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`

`"models": {
    "": {
        "dataSource": "mainService",
        "preload": true,
        "settings" : {
          "useBatch" : true,
          "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
          "defaultCountMode" : "None",
          //default is sap.ui.model.odata.UpdateMethod.Merge
          "defaultUpdateMethod" : "Put"
        }
    }
}`

```
var sPath = oView.getBindingContext().getPath();
oModel.setDeferredGroups(["editGroup"]);
oModel.update(sPath, oData, {groupId: "editGroup"});
oModel.update(sPath, oData2, {groupId: "editGroup"});
oModel.submitChanges({
    groupId: "editGroup",
    success: this.successCallback, 
    error: this.errorCallback
});
```

Actually, v2.ODataModel will useBatch by default, use `update()`/`create()`/`delete()` without `setDeferredGroups()` and `submitChanges()` is OK. But in that way, I will get callback for each request, I use `submitChanges` to merge the responses to one.