# sapui5 batch with sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel

Tags: odata, sapui5

I created table with data using JSONModel

```
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(query);
    oTablePrio = sap.ui.getCore().getControl("idTablePrio2");
    oTablePrio.setModel(oModel, "Prio2");
```

Everythink look and work good.

Now i have added new column(prio) where i will change value. After changing i would like to save every rows( in the SAP ztable ) after clicking buton save .
I made something like this

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(gServiceUrl);
        oModel.setUseBatch(true);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sEntry.Matnr = data[i].Matnr;
            sEntry.Bbynr = data[i].Bbynr;
            sEntry.Prio = data[i].Prio;

oModel.update("/WielosztSet('"+data[i].Bbynr+"')", sEntry, {
                  method: "PUT",  function(){
                alert('Data Updated Successfully');
                 location.reload(true);
                  },function(){
                        sap.m.MessageToast.show('Update failed',{duration:1000});

                  }});
}
```

Now only it sends data only with the last row. 
I wrote that i cannot update more than one row in this way and I need to make batch. 
I connot find how to create working batch for uploding data with  `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Why don't you work with OData model directly? You could bind your table to OData model and get all the updates for free just with the "submitChanges" call, and they will be batched automatically.

Comment: sounds, greate. Could you tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Instead of thouthand words: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html#loio6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2

Comment: I created Model like this:
' var gServiceUrl =  "proxy/http/app-xxx.com:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPMR_KONFLIKTY/?&sap-client=200";
var goModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel({ 
    serviceUrl: gServiceUrl,    
});`
And i tried to bind data to sap.m.table but nothing happens.
`
oTablePrio2.bindItems("Prio2>/d/results/", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
       cells : [ 
        new sap.m.Text({ text : "{Prio2>Bbynr}"}),
`
What can be the reason?

Comment: Are you able to get data back via "read" method?

Comment: it is hard to say. There is no error, but still no data in table
i made line like this 
goModel.read("/WielosztSet('000000000064')");
it works in SAP

Comment: What to you see in network tab? Is there valid response? You can attach "success" callback to the "read" call and see the result in arguments. "it works in SAP" - what does it mean?

Comment: i made code like this
goModel.read("/WielosztSet('000000000064')", {success: function(oData, response) {

                len=oData.results.length;

                 alert(len); 
         },failed: function(oData, response) {

          alert("Failed to get InputHelpValues from service!");

          }     
In network tab i have 
URL: /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPMR_KONFLIKTY/?&sap-client=200 
METHOD: HEAD 
CODE 200 
and dont knwo why
METHOD: POST
CODE: 202
URL: /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPMR_KONFLIKTY/$batch?&sap-client=200
btw. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: So the question is: do you see the response data in network tab ?

Comment: Hmmm it looks like it teruns something:
http://prntscr.com/gc28i4

other tabs:
http://prntscr.com/gc242d
http://prntscr.com/gc268c

Comment: ok, looks that the data call is correct. You need to bind your table to the odatamodel (see the ui5 documentation) and then all the changes to the bound fields, should automatically be updated by the model and the only thing you should do is to call "submitChanges"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will keep trying to bind oDatav2 to my table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582351/sapui5-batch-operations-how-to-do-it-right

Answer (score 0):

Before the call of the oModel.update assign the UseBatch to true:

```
oModel.setUseBatch(true);
```

Make your for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sEntry.Matnr = data[i].Matnr;
            sEntry.Bbynr = data[i].Bbynr;
            sEntry.Prio = data[i].Prio;

oModel.update("/WielosztSet('"+data[i].Bbynr+"')", sEntry, {
                  method: "PUT",  function(){
                alert('Data Updated Successfully');
                 location.reload(true);
                  },function(){
                        sap.m.MessageToast.show('Update failed',{duration:1000});

                  }});
}
```

At the end of for put the submitChanges.

```
oModel.submitChanges();
oModel.setUseBatch(false); // Make false if you reuse this oModel.
```

Regards.