# sapui5 Posting data in batch call using OData Service

Tags: odata, sapui5

Im trying to post data in batch call using OData service. But im getting Error like **HTTP Request Failed**. Im not able to find the exact error. Can some one please help me to fix this?
Below is my code..

```
var payloadTest = {
        "Userid" : "",
        "RecId" : "000000012651",
        "Pernr" : "00039411",
        "Ename" : "Investment Test",
        "AttAbsType" : "TT01",
        "MarkAbst" : "",
        "Count" : 0,
    }

batchChanges.push(that.ODataModel.createBatchOperation(
                    "TestService('123')", "POST", payloadTest));

that.ODataModel.addBatchChangeOperations(batchChanges);
            that.ODataModel.setUseBatch(true);
            that.ODataModel.submitBatch(function(data, value) {
                that.ODataModel.refresh();

                if (data.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses) {
                    that.busyDialog.close();
                    MessageBox.success(data.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses.length);
                } else {
                    that.busyDialog.close();
                    MessageBox.error(data.__batchResponses[0].message);
                }

            }, function(err) {
                that.busyDialog.close();
                MessageBox.error("Error occurred", err);
            });
```

Please see the below error description in below image..
[image]

Please help me to fix the issue..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you aware that you use an extremely old version of odata model?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says "Bad Request" ... means your request body is simply wrong.

[SAPUI5 - Batch Operations - how to do it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582351/sapui5-batch-operations-how-to-do-it-right)